# Making a particular bit "0" in C++

Tags: c++, bit

I'm new at programming. Recently i came across a problem in which i have to make a particular bit 0 of a number.

For example :

I have a number p

```
p      = 73
binary = 1001001
```

Now i want to make 4th bit to 0, that is 1000001(2) = 65(10)

I did this in following way :

```
int p = 73;
int pos = 1<<3; // 4th bit
int max_bit = (1<<31) - 1; // making all bit to 1
int mask = pos ^ max_bit; // making 4th bit to 0 except others
p = p & mask; // changing 4th bit of p to 0
cout<<p<<endl;
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: just as a "did you know": that is called clearing a bit. Making it "1" is called setting a bit

Comment: no i didn't know that :( but i do now :) thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use :

```
p = p & ~(1u<<3);
```

What happens here ?

```
 1. (1u<<3)       0...01000
 2. ~(1u<<3)      1...10111 // Invert the bits
 3. p & ~(1u<<3)  *****0*** // Here * means the bit representation of p
```

That's how the bit changes to 0.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Maybe add an explanation for those not familiar with bit manipulation?

Comment: @jpw okay.. i'm adding an explanation

Comment: I think, may be better is to write `p & ~(1u << n);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes you are right. But OP using `int` so i think `1<<pos`will solve the problem

Comment: no I means it can be undefined behaviour if singed bit set but I am not sure about C++ standards. Anyways this is simple and good answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you are right :)

Comment: Use `p &= ~(1u<<3);` instead.